# How to validate version number using regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate version number pattern for following examples:

```
A1
aabc1
AabC134
aabc12.2
aA1.2.3
0.1.1
0.0.2
a.b.c
a.1.2
a.0.0
1.0.0
1.0
1
```

Basically it should allow alphanum in all three parts (split parts by dot)
but it cannot be:

```
0
0.0.0
000.000.000
0000.00.00
```

I have tried this regex but it allows zeros:

```
/([A-Za-z\d]+)?(.*[A-Za-z\d]+)?(.*[A-Za-z\d]+)$
```

Can it be modified to achieve above results?

Comment: `/^(?![0.]+$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+){0,2}$/`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3pMUl/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It still allows `0` and `0.0.0` etc

Comment: No, it does not. Check https://regex101.com/r/w3pMUl/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes now it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?![0.]+$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+){0,2}$/
```

Or,

```
/^(?![0.]+$)[A-Z\d]+(?:\.[A-Z\d]+){0,2}$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3pMUl/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![0.]+$)` - no just zeros / dots till the end of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` -  one or more digits/letters
- `(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+){0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits or letters
- `$` - end of string

[Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F!%5B0.%5D%2B%24)%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B)%7B0%2C2%7D%24):

[image]

Comment: That's Perfect for my scenario! Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: While your answer may be streamlined and correct, were this regex to appear inside some application code, I would much rather see a plain sight blacklist of version numbers.  Imagine if you move on, and someone else inherits your code.  Would that person be able to figure out that `(?![0.]+$)` were intended to block the four version numbers given in the OP?

Answer (score 2):

I might just use negative lookaheads to assert that the blacklisted version numbers do not appear, and otherwise proceed along the lines of what you are already doing:

```
 ^(?!^(?:0|0\.0\.0|000\.000\.000|0000\.00\.00)$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+){0,2}$
```

### Demo